# Limit value to a maximum

Tags: ruby, math

```
@a = 200
@b = 1

@c = @a / @b
```

`@c` is going to equal 200. How can I institute a max value for `@c` to be 100?

```
if @c = 99, do nothing
if @c = 100, do nothing
if @c > 100, make @c 100
```

In SQL, this is the `LEAST` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Enumerable#min`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-min) works:

```
[@c, 100].min
```

Answer (score -1):

```
case @c
 when  99
   ##   do something
 when  100
   ##   do something
 else
  @c = 100 if @c > 100 
  # or
  @c = [@c, 100].min # inspired by minitech answer
end
```

Comment: @minitech, what did i miss ? can you brief

Comment: I think the answer promotes good code habits with expected answer

Comment: The point is to find the minimum of two numbers. The 99 and 100 "do nothing" and were just examples. The `if @c > 100 then @c = 100 end` is the only case where something happens.

Comment: @minitech, I understand your point, but the lines `if @c = 99, do nothing
if @c = 100, do nothing` confused me and made me to think so , I think  the questions need to just preciosly say only do `if @c > 100 @c = 100 ` the other examples mislead , also I dont see any point to be incorrect as the question just also says only do `if @c > 100, make @c 100`